# Application Startup Icon Locked (root)

Tags: nautilus, icons, .desktop

I have installed a program, an icon appears on the desktop, but it has a picture of a lock on it, and clicking it does nothing.

It's a program I installed from a file. /home/roger/Downloads/General_PSS-Linux_Eng_Suse_IS_V1.00.0.R.120618.tar.bz2

I have root access, but have not been able to change the permissions.
gksudo Nautilus won't work for me

sudo su won't work for me

@^&^&((&%^ - change, you %$%&^*(+ doesn't work either.

I'm probably not going about it correctly.

What do you advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start an application if it's not executable.

To make it executable use the following command. For example, if I had a file "mycoolapp" in my Desktop folder, I would type this:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/mycoolapp
```

and so you don't have to be root to run the app you need to gain ownership over the file

use the chown command to regain ownership of the file

```
sudo chown -R roger:roger ~/
```

This command will give you ownership over every file in /home/roger/

Also, to start Nautilus with root permissions you have to use sudo or gksud

```
sudo nautilus
```

or

```
gksudo nautilus
```

From there you can right-click on the offending file and select properties and then permissions. If you need to make the file executable to run it as a program, make sure the file is check marked as executable.

Comment: Don't know for sure what I did wrong, but got these messages :


roger@roger-desktop:~$ gksudo nautilus.


Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory 
/var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:4372): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 99 was not found when attempting to remove it

(nautilus:4372): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 101 was not found when attempting to remove it
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: The lock is gone from the icon, but the app still won't start.

Comment: It may be loooking for a file called libXV.so.1 that doesn't exist.

./PSS : error while loading shared libraries: libXV.so.1 : cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory

What can I do about this?